# How to copy/store a scope variable's original value without updating it when the scope variable updates

Tags: angularjs

I have a simple task which turned out to be not so simple.. I need to take a copy of a `$scope` variable, without using `angular.copy()`, because if I use the copy function, the object can't be compared to a watcher's `newVal` if a change is made, because it's not the same object. So `if (newVal !== original)` will never evaluate to `false`. How can I store the original value of a scope variable but never update this variable again, even when the scope variable changes? Is it possible?

```
core.directive('saveButton', function () {

    return {
        scope: {
            actionParams: '=',
        },
        templateUrl: 'app/views/components/core/save-button.html',
        link: function(scope, element, attrs) {

            var original = scope.actionParams;

            scope.$watch(function() {
                return scope.actionParams;
            }, function(newVal, oldVal) {

                // I want to check if the original value has changed, not the previous value
                if (newVal !== original) {
                    scope.changed = true;
                }
                else {
                    scope.changed = false;
                }
            }, true);
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Have you given this a try? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29546930/is-the-angular-scope-binding-ampersand-a-one-time-binding

Comment: @jcc Yes, doesn't work either :/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

just store json representation - it will never change and you can always compare it to json representation of new value.
https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.toJson

or you can compare objects using angular.equals:
`angular.equals({b : { c : [1, 2]}, a : 'a'}, {a : 'a', b : { c : [1, 2]}})` >> true

Comment: Actually worked, but man is it ugly.. But couldn't care less after 3h of trying :P cheers!