# When to use AngularJS's one time binding (i.e. `<`) introduced in 1.5?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Given

```
<my-component my-attr="parentModel">
```

and a directive definition that includes:

```
scope: { localModel:'<myAttr' }
```

angular [will set up a one time binding](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$compile#-scope-). What this means is that

> The expression is evaluated in the context of the parent scope

and

> the isolated scope property localModel will reflect the value of parentModel on the parent scope. Any changes to parentModel will be reflected in localModel, but changes in localModel will not reflect in parentModel

This is great, but how is anything accomplished above what is already accomplishable with an angular expression using ampersand notation (i.e. `&`)?

Given

```
<my-component my-attr="parentModel">
```

and a directive definition that includes:

```
scope: { getModel:'&myAttr' }
```

any calls to `scope.getModel()` should also evaluate the `"parentModel"` expression in the context of the parent scope and provide such value to the isolated scope of the directive, and here there is no need to`$watch` the `parentModel` or to worry about values in the isolate scope propagating back up to the parent.

Comment: Why not `@` vs `&` or  `@` vs `<` then? `&` and `<` are oranges and apples. `&` evaluates an expression in parent context. `<` provides the binding of scope prop. `&` is good for function call in parent context (an alternative to A2 event emitter), `scope.localModel()` smells awfully. `<` is there to fill a gap for 1.5 to 2.0 migration in the first place.

Comment: @estus you wouldn't call it `scope.localModel()`. Was just keeping name for comparison. It'd be more like `scope.someBehavior()`

Comment: @estus I guess my question is why would you bind a prop to scope that receives one directional updates from parent when you can accomplish the same thing with a function.  Does it just boil down to a style/preference thing maybe?

Comment: And you can do this with `{{ parentModel }}` @ binding, aren't you? This is a matter of taste to some degree, but it is just more awkward with & binding.

Comment: < will throw if binding is not proper. @ and & will choke because they evaluate expression, not bind a prop. So that's it. & is there for sharing behaviour with parent scope. < is there for sharing a prop with parent scope. This conforms to `[]` and `()` bindings in A2.

Comment: @estus You can only do {{ parentModel }} with an @ binding if you're ok with a string being passed through, which obviously troublesome in the case of `"true"` and possibly `"5"`. `'&'` provides the more general functionality. I hear you though, could be more natural to bind a property and reference a property instead of invoking a func that wraps an expression. I haven't looks at A2 yet either, and I can see it being relevent for migration and such

Answer (score 1):

I made this code snippet to try to understand the question better. It seems like there are obvious differences between the two options such as how the `link` function is handled and some auto `$watch()ing`. But I'd never used an expression in this way and I think I'm missing something.

```js
var app = angular.module('app', []);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function() {
  this.v1 = 1;
  this.v2 = 2;
  this.v3 = 3;
});

app.directive('myComponentOne',
  function() {
    return {
      restrict: 'E',
      scope: { v: "<val" },
      template: '<input ng-model="v"/>',
      link: s => s.v = 99
    };
  });

app.directive('myComponentTwo',
  function() {
    return {
      restrict: 'E',
      scope: { v: '&val' },
      template: '<input ng-model="v"/>',
      link: s => s.v = 99
    };
  });

app.directive('myComponentThree',
  function() {
    return {
      restrict: 'E',
      scope: { v: '=val' },
      template: '<input ng-model="v"/>',
      link: s => s.v = 99
    };
  });
```

```html
<div ng-app="app">
  <div ng-controller="MainCtrl as main">
    <div>
      One-way binding:<br>
      parentScope=<input ng-model="main.v1" /><br>
      localScope=<my-component-one val="main.v1"></my-component-one>
    </div>
    <hr>
    <div>
      Expression:<br>
      parentScope=<input ng-model="main.v2" /><br>
      localScope=<my-component-two val="main.v2"></my-component-two>
    </div>
    <hr>
    <div>
      Two-way binding:<br>
      parentScope=<input ng-model="main.v3" /><br>
      localScope=<my-component-three val="main.v3"></my-component-three>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.1/angular.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer/snippet.This doesn't capture the problem completely though b/c `component-two` doesn't make use of an expression correctly. Setting `s.v = 99` in the linkFn overrides the wrapping expression.And even if you left the exp as is, the `v` in `<input ng-model="v"/>` now points at a function. Adding `ng-model-options="{getterSetter: true}"` won't help either b/c the wrapped exp in this case is only a getter. A better test might be something like `{{v()}}` in the case of `&` of `{{v}}` in the case of `<`.You can set an ng-click="v=10" in the latter case to test that it's one way